# is there a way to only join games that have not started yet?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I am sick of joining in a game with it half over already. is there a way or a setting to change where I only join games while they are in the lobby?

Answer (score 4):

short and simple: no, all you can do is pray and hope.